# Keep MathKernel Running In Background - Speed Up Execution Time

Tags: kernel, real-time

**Background:** I'm running Debian on a remote server with Mathematica installed.  I have several dozen small mathematica files that are run in cron jobs at unpredictable intervals and updated based on a web interface.  I'm trying to get  faster response times when I run the smaller files.

**Question:** For Example I have `file.m` which contains(This is just an example)

```
Export["/home/rob/Desktop/eq.png",Sum[1/2,{x,i}]]
```

If I setup a cron job to run the following

```
time MathKernel -noprompt -script /home/rob/Desktop/file.m
```

I get a real response time of **`6.31`**.

But now if I ssh into the server and run `MathKernel` and the following

```
AbsoluteTiming[Export["/home/rob/Desktop/eq.png",HoldForm[Sum[1/2,{x,i}]]]
```

the script returns **`1.13`**.

The start up time definitely appears to be the issue `6.31` vs `1.13`.

So what is the best way to keep MathKernel running it the background so it can periodically run `file.m`?
I would like to avoid using `CreateScheduledTask` because of the extensive rewrite that would be needed.

**EDIT:**[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61242/watch-file-in-directory-net) and [this](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) are clunky but should work.

Comment: Related: [41742](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41742)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spawn1701D's idea to use `$IgnoreEOF` is interesting, but unfortunately this flag doesn't work at all in version 9, and it doesn't work when reading from files in version 8.

Instead we can use the `tail` Unix utility to prevent Mathematica from stopping to read input.

1. Create a pipe: `mkfifo mmpipe`
2. Execute `tail -f mmpipe | math`.  `tail` will keep feeding Mathematica from whatever is written to `mmpipe`.
3. Pipe input to `mmpipe`, e.g. `echo 1+1 > mmpipe`.  Mathematica will execute it.  You can do this as many times as needed.

Just make sure that every input you give Mathematica is complete and correct.  An unclosed bracket could make this approach fail.

---

A more robust solution would use MathLink to feed expressions to Mathematica (this is what the Front End does).  This would take more work to implement.

---

**EDIT:** You'll find some more information about this method and its shortcomings [in this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41742/12).

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use `cat mmpipe` instead of `tail -f mmpipe`?  I was under the impression tail prints on the last 10 lines of its input.  Also do you know of any way to the simultaneously write the mathematica repl input and output to maybe a log file?  Although MathkLink is probably the best solution, but it would nice to have a way to view past commands and maybe errors to run commands in a log file.

Comment: @Liam Look up the `-f` option to `tail`.  This is the essential bit that keeps the system from stopping as soon as the pipe is out of data. You'd have to test if it truncates though ... I'm not too good with Unix commands so I can't answer your second question, but take a look at `tee`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the variable `$IgnoreEOF` to `True`. Actually as the first job you can give the command

```
MathKernel -noprompt -script /home/rob/Desktop/init.m
```

where in `init.m` you have the command

```
$IgnoreEOF = True
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to give an explicit `Quit` now to kill the MathKernel.

Comment: So let's say I have `file2.m`.  How would I take advantage of the already running `MathKernel` instance?  It appears to just never end now.

Comment: @Liam You mean that if you give `MathKenel -run "Quit[]"` it doesn't quit?

Comment: @Liam You are right the next time you run MathKernel it opens a new process. Put how about using the `CreateScheduledTask` command to emulate the function of cron? With `IgnoreEOF = True` the kernel will not exit after reading the initial file with the scheduled tasks and at random times the files you want will be run be the scheduler.

Comment: @Spawn170D I had thought about using `CreateScheduledTask` before posting the question, but I really don't think it would be practical.  The cron jobs are modified on a fairly regular basis.  Additionally I have had mathematica force quit before.  The entire automation of the system would go down if mathematica dies once. To help others, I'm going to edit the question to exclude `CreateScheduledTask` as a possibility.

Comment: @Liam but the only think you will have to do is to kill the current session running the jobs and start the new one. Mathematica will not affected as you have see every MathKernel runs its own process. Actually in the script you can have a task that will check the jobs file and if changed to start the new one.

Comment: Yes but the cron jobs are updated based on a web interface.  I don't see how to link mathematica to the cron jobs(without rewriting part of the web interface).

Comment: @Liam yes I see what you mean, except if the file intended for the cron scheduler can be also read by Mathematica.

Comment: `$IgnoreEOF=True` doesn't prevent it from quitting here ... otherwise I guess it would be possible to create a pipe (`mkfifo`), make `math` read commands from there and feed the commands periodically.