# Run mathematica scripts without initializing the kernel every time

Tags: windows, scripting

There are [two duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41742)'s of this question that seem to only work on linux/osx currently.

So how can I viably run mathematica scripts without spawning a new session each time from command prompt?

I would like to support stdout.

Comment: Please to not use the `bugs` tag initially, even if it clearly seems to be the case; by community convention it is applied later.  Also, links to the duplicates would seem highly appropriate.

Comment: I'm also interesting for this question on Windows

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to initialize the kernel each time?  Are the scripts particularly fast running?  The overhead in restarting the kernel may be relatively trivial and does guarantee that the kernel is clean (as its going to be) at the start of each run.

Comment: @Ymareth Yes they are fast running.  6 secs vs 1 sec are a big difference.    [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23217/) question is related.

Comment: @Bendesarts the current answer works with some caveats.

Comment: This is alternative technique completely.

[Simple enabling run on start works well.][1]


  [1]: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9484/running-an-initialization-cell-on-mathematica-start-up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for running scripts.  Print is not supported although the last return value defaults to the stdout.

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
InstallNET[];

ShowNETConsole["stdout"];
LoadNETType["System.Console"];
Console`Out@WriteLine["Hello from .NET"];

WatchFile[file_String, fun_] := 
  Module[{time, time2, w, e}, 
   w = NETNew["System.IO.FileSystemWatcher"];
   LoadNETType["System.IO.NotifyFilters"];
   LoadNETType["System.IO.File"];
   w@Path = FileNameJoin@Drop[FileNameSplit[file], -1];
   w@NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters`LastWrite;
   w@Filter = Last@FileNameSplit[file];
   e = AddEventHandler[w@Changed, myHandler];
   time = 0;
   myHandler[source_, 
     e_] := (time2 = File`GetLastWriteTime[file]@ToBinary[];
     If[time == time2, Null;, fun[source, e];];
     time = time2;);
   w@EnableRaisingEvents = True;
   Return[{w, e}];];
WatchFile["C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\in.txt", Function[{w, e},
  Export[FileNameJoin@
     Insert[Drop[FileNameSplit@e@FullPath, -1], "out.txt", -1], 
    ToExpression@Import[e@FullPath]];
  ]]
```

and the c# script.

```
using System;

public class Watcher
{
    public static int exit=1;
    static DateTime lastRead = DateTime.MinValue;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\a\Desktop\in.txt", String.Join(" ", args));
        System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = "C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop";
        watcher.NotifyFilter = System.IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Filter = "out.txt";
        watcher.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        while (exit != 0) ;
    }
    private static void OnChanged(object source, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime lastWriteTime = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(e.FullPath);
        if (lastWriteTime != lastRead)
        {
            Console.Write(
              System.IO.File.ReadAllText(e.FullPath)
            );
            exit = 0;
            lastRead = lastWriteTime;
        }
    }
}
```

compile script.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe test.cs
```