# Execute code when file is modified in Mathematica 12.0

Tags: dynamic

I have a text file called `file.txt` that is being modified every few seconds by an external program (my Stenography machine's software).

`myCode` is a program which takes as input a `List` called `data` which is `Import`ed from `file.txt`.

### How can I execute `myCode` everytime this file is modified?

The following code does not work but looks like what I need.

```
file = NotebookDirectory[] <> "file.txt";
Dynamic[
    Refresh[
        fileSize := FileByteCount[file];
        data = Import[file, "Table"];
        myCode[data]
        ,TrackedSymbols :> {fileSize}
    ]
]
```

- to help de-abstract the problem, here is are two example cases of `myCode` and `file.txt`

  ```
  myCode[data_] := Style[ListLinePlot[Flatten[data], PlotTheme -> "Marketing"], Magnification -> 2];
  Export[NotebookDirectory[]<>"file.txt", {1, 2, 3}]
  ```

[This question has been asked 8 years ago for Mathematica 9.0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15935/execute-code-when-file-is-modified). Sadly the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15938/36681) provided then does not work in Mathematica 12.0

### Note: I am not interested in repeatedly executing `myCode` every $n$ seconds. I only want to execute `myCode` *IF* `file.txt` is modified.

---

I'm afraid I oversimplified my question above. I wanted to try and present a minimal example. My true problem is below:

`myCode` is a program which takes the last element of `data` (a list of integers `Import`ed from `file.txt`) and computes the ratio with the last element of another list (imported from another file which is **sometimes** modified (when this second file is modified it is modified at the same time $t$ as when `file.txt` is modified)). `myCode` then `AppendsTo` this ratio to a third list (which is then plotted). I **only** want it to do this operation if `file.txt` is modified.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the outcome of running the linked code is? How does it “not work”?

Comment: Try this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104118/5478

Comment: Thanks @Kuba. That looks like what I need.

Comment: if you are happy with Kuba's suggestion there is nothing wrong with it. On the other hand, there is the concept of a "file system watcher" which will allow to call a function when a file changes without polling for changes. In [this QA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61242/169) you will find an example of this using NETLink. If you are not on Windows, there is similar functionality for Java...

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code. You request that the code inside `Request` is executed every 5 seconds. AT the same time you specify `TrackedSymbols :> {fileSize}` what means, that the code should be executed when `fileSize`changes. But this is not necessary because the code is executed every 5 seconds anyway.

Here is a code example that runs on version 12.1:

```
 myCode[d_] = ListLinePlot[d];
Dynamic[
 data = Import[file];
 myCode[data], UpdateInterval -> 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid I oversimplified my problem. I **only** want to execute  `myCode` when `file.txt` is modified. I do not want to execute it every $n$ seconds. I hate asking complicated questions but I have added a short description to the bottom of my question. Your answer is nevertheless good because it explains how to `Dynamical`ly use `Import`.

Comment: That is easily fixed. Check every 5 seconds if the file changed and only update it if so. To check if it changed, the method with ByteCount can be used, but the problem is when the file changed, but the length stays the same. An other method would be to calculate a hash. Can you make the change yourself?

Comment: Yes I can make the change myself using a text editor.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I used them in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

### update: A superior solution can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/239929/36681)

---

Here is a simple solution using [`FinishDynamic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinishDynamic.html) inside a `While` loop that checks every $\Delta t$ seconds for changes and runs `myCode` **once** if a change is detected:

### step 1

Execute:

```
Dynamic[x]
```

### step 2

Run a `While` loop that calculates one `FileHash` of `file.txt` before and another `FileHash` after a small interval $\Delta t$. In each iteration: use an `If` statement to check if the hashes are equal or not. If they are not equal then `myCode` is executed. [`FinishDynamic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinishDynamic.html) pauses the `While` loop during each iteration until the output of `myCode` is rendered in the [`Dynamic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) cell above the cell containing the `While` loop.

```
Δt = 0.1;
file = NotebookDirectory[] <> "file.txt";
myCode[data_] := Style[ListLinePlot[Flatten[data], PlotTheme -> "Marketing"], Magnification -> 2];

While[True,
      FinishDynamic[];
      fileHashT = FileHash[file];
      Pause[Δt];
      fileHashTplusΔt = FileHash[file];
      
      If[ fileHashT != fileHashTplusΔt,
      
          data = Import[file, "Table"];
          x = myCode[data]
       ]   
]
```

[image]

---

### note:

in this example, `file.txt` was created with:

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[]<>"file.txt",{1,2,3}]//SystemOpen
```

Comment: It seems like you should be able to do this with the sort of functionality in the answer you linked to, no?

Comment: @CATrevillian You are right! A small modification to the linked answer makes it work with Mathematica 12.0. Thanks.